# Use a variable in cursor SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I've written a stored procedure that will take a parent part, go through the  bill-of-materials records for that part and conditionally concatenate matching child-records (i.e. the parts which are included in this part's BOM), but only child-records that meet certain criteria (using our naming convention, anything starting with '.', 'E', or 'ZG').

I have created the SP and it works beautifully, but only when I pass in an [optional] parent part number. I need to run this SP for all parts, so my thought was to execute the SP inside of a cursor, and keep passing in the next part until there are none left to process. I can't work out how to do this, or if it's even possible, because in the cursor's SELECT statement, (in which I'm using the stored procedure code) I need to pass in a variable for it to work.

Here is the code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_BuildBOMLit
@item_no CHAR(8) = NULL 
AS 
BEGIN
WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.item_no)) as item_no, LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) as comp_item_no,
            CASE
                WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) LIKE '.%' 
                    THEN 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no))
                WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) LIKE 'E%' 
                    THEN
                        (SELECT TOP 1 LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no)) FROM bmprdstr_sql WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(item_no))=LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no))  AND LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no)) LIKE '.%')
                WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) LIKE 'ZG%'
                    THEN 
                        (SELECT TOP 1 LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no)) FROM bmprdstr_sql WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(item_no))=LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no))  AND LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no)) LIKE '.%')
                    ELSE
                        NULL
            END as lvl_2_comp_item_no
        FROM 
            bmprdstr_sql as lvl1 
            LEFT JOIN bmprdstr_sql lvl2 ON lvl1.comp_item_no=lvl2.item_no
        WHERE 
            (lvl1.item_no = @item_no)
            AND (lvl1.comp_item_no LIKE '.%' OR lvl1.comp_item_no LIKE 'ZG%' OR lvl1.comp_item_no LIKE 'E%')
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE
            WHEN LEFT(item_no,1)='.'
                THEN STUFF(item_no,1,1,'')
            ELSE
                item_no
        END as item_no,
        part_no = 
            STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 
                    CASE
                        WHEN LEFT(lvl_2_comp_item_no,1)='.'
                            THEN STUFF(lvl_2_comp_item_no,1,1,'')
                        ELSE lvl_2_comp_item_no
                        END
                    FROM CTE where item_no=@item_no FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE
        lvl_2_comp_item_no IS NOT NULL AND item_no IS NOT NULL
END
```

Output is exactly the format I need:

## item_no | part_no

JM9027  | GS10702,LB2391,LB2704,LB2834,LB2896,LB6996

When I create the cursor, I'm using the same code in the cursor's `SELECT` statement, but as you can see if requires the parent (`@itemno`) to be passed in. I have tried this, to no avail:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @itemno CHAR(15);
 DECLARE @partno VARCHAR(254);
 DECLARE @outside_cursor AS CURSOR;

SET @outside_cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT DISTINCT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.item_no)) AS item_no,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) AS comp_item_no,
        CASE
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) LIKE '.%' 
                THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no))
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) LIKE 'E%' 
                THEN
                    (SELECT TOP 1 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no))
                    FROM 
                        bmprdstr_sql
                    WHERE 

LTRIM(RTRIM(item_no))=LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no))
                        AND LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no)) LIKE '.%'
                    )
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no)) LIKE 'ZG%' 
                THEN
                    (SELECT TOP 1 
                        LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no))
                    FROM 
                        bmprdstr_sql
                    WHERE 

LTRIM(RTRIM(item_no))=LTRIM(RTRIM(lvl1.comp_item_no))
                        AND LTRIM(RTRIM(comp_item_no)) LIKE '.%'
                    )
            ELSE NULL
        END AS lvl_2_comp_item_no
 FROM 
    bmprdstr_sql AS lvl1
    LEFT JOIN bmprdstr_sql lvl2 ON lvl1.comp_item_no=lvl2.item_no
 WHERE 
    (lvl1.item_no = @itemno) -- <-- problem
     AND (lvl1.comp_item_no LIKE '.%' OR lvl1.comp_item_no LIKE 'ZG%' 
OR lvl1.comp_item_no LIKE 'E%')
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE
        WHEN LEFT(item_no,1)='.' 
            THEN STUFF(item_no,1,1,'')
        ELSE item_no
    END AS item_no,
    part_no = 
        STUFF(
            (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN LEFT(lvl_2_comp_item_no,1)='.' 
                        THEN STUFF(lvl_2_comp_item_no,1,1,'') 
                    ELSE lvl_2_comp_item_no 
                END
            FROM 
                CTE
            WHERE 
                item_no=@itemno FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
                     -- ^ problem
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    lvl_2_comp_item_no IS NOT NULL
    AND item_no IS NOT NULL 

OPEN @outside_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @outside_cursor INTO @itemno, @partno;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO items_parts (item_no, part_no)
        VALUES (@itemno, @partno) 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @outside_cursor INTO @itemno,  @partno 
    END 
CLOSE @outside_cursor 
DEALLOCATE @outside_cursor
```

Any advice on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Not sure why you are using a cursor for inserting data. I didn't try to parse this big query to really see what it is doing but this can be rewritten as a single set based insert. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange Every question about SQL cursors end up with this comment in one form or another.  I tried using a set-based approach before I went to the cursor.

Comment: That is because nearly every cursor can be solved with a set based approach instead of RBAR.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding whether you even need a cursor, and treating your question as academic, you are using the cursor the wrong way.

You have a proc that does what you want, but only for one parent.  The way to incorporate a cursor would be to use the cursor to iterate through the parents and simply populate your item_no variable with a new item_no each time it loops, and then run your existing code inside the cursor.

You don't need to do the SELECT and then the INSERT in two separate queries, you can do a single INSERT..SELECT in your cursor.   The cursor just iterates through your list of item_no values.

Comment: When you say I don't need to do the SELECT and INSERT in separate queries, are you saying I could perform the INSERT...SELECT in the cursor definition? Like `SET @outside_cursor = CURSOR FAST FORWARD FOR INSERT INTO items_parts VALUES @itemno, @partno WITH CTE AS (SELECT....)`, then in the WHILE loop just call `FETCH NEXT`?

Comment: No, the cursor definition is just a SELECT of the `item_no`'s that you want to use as your `@itemno` variable.  The INSERT..SELECT is the operation that you put inside the cursor loop, so it is performed for each `item_no`.

Comment: Appreciate your help @Tab Alleman. I was able to accomplish this without using a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I see;

I think what you have is a CTE which returns a single row of data (or perhaps (n) rows of data but only unique to the @itemno)

```
    CTE(item_no, comp_item_no, lvl_2_comp_item_no) 
      AS (
            --.... and the row will correspond to the @itemno provided
```

but what you want instead is CTE which returns the value set **for all possible [ietm_no]** (something which should result in a temp table behind the scenes with 3 columns [item_no], [comp_item_no], [lvl_2_comp_item_no] with (n) rows.

Then you can use your CURSOR to loop through these one-by-one, load them up into the CURSOR VARIABLES  i.e.:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @outside_cursor INTO @itemno, @partno...
```

and process the insert for each row with unique @itemno.

*BTW, I've noticed that you named your cursor as @outside_cursor which implies that there could be an @inside_cursor as well somewhere ? In case you are nesting cursors (which is not the best choice) please note the  @@FETCH_STATUS is a global variable and you'll need to manage the value in this variable separate for each cursor.*

Am I seeing this right ?

Comment: The result of the CTE is the parent item_no repeats in the item_no column, the comp_item_no is the first child-level below the parent, and if the comp_item_no value starts with '.', 'E', or 'ZG', it performs a subquery and finds any children to THAT item that match the same criteria.

The following query then strips the '.' from the front of the item_no if there is one, and concatenates all of the lvl_2_comp_item_no's into a comma-separated list.

Also, the cursor is named `@outside_cursor` because I had been trying to solve this by creating a nested cursor and just never renamed it.

Comment: ok, that's good that the cursor is not nested and how about my suggestion above? It seems you are not using the cursor the right way. I think you need to load the data set for all itemno's and then process it one by one... makes sense ?

Comment: What you describe is ultimately what I want the result to be, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to use to return the data without using a variable in the CTE. I'm going to try what you suggest  and execute the SP open to insert all data into a temp table before defining and running the cursor to iterate over the rows. I'll report back - thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Just try to simplify the CTE so it returns the data for all item_no (basically remove the @itemno from the syntax) then SELECT * from the CTE and see what you have. You should see a lot of rows which could be loaded up into your CURSOR. Let me know if that worked...

Comment: I appreciate your help @Milan. I was able to accomplish this without using a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help with this issue. I went back to the drawing board and was able to accomplish what I needed with the stored procedure and a self-joining query - no cursor needed.